Calculating Price/Earnings Ratios for Indices
Since there are different ways of calculating the forward P/E ratio of an index, I am uncertain as to which method is common practice. In this respect, I have two questions:

In the factsheet for the S&P 400 dated July 31st, it states that the 'P/E (Projected)' is 16.36. However, the factsheet for the SPDR S&P 400 ETF from the same date reports a 'Price/Earnings Ratio FY1' of 17.50. Given that the ETF's tracking error is very low, why is there a relatively large discrepancy in the reported P/E ratios?

The STOXX 600 factsheet provides both a projected P/E ratio that includes negative earnings and one that excludes them. When other indices do not specify this, are negative earnings typically included or excluded?


